# Как сделать многостраничный сайт с передачей id на другую страницу?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите разобраться. Есть задача сделать простой сайт на 2 страницы с помощью VanillaJS. У меня есть index.html, в котором я получаю данные с API (новостная лента). У каждой новости есть свой id в формате *the-university-of-discovery/2021/sep/20/the...*. При клике на любую новость должна открываться страница news.html, и в ней показываться именно та новость, по которой кликнули.
Я думаю, что на index.html нужно задавать для каждой новости ссылку в формате a href=“news/:id” и прокидывать id элемента по url. А дальше что? Неужели делать простой сервер на ноде и создавать роутинг по каждому запросу url?

Comment: На второй странице у вас уже есть нужный id в адресе. Остаётся достать id из адреса и запросить например через fetch данные этой новости, допустим это будет файл json или кусок html. После получения данных нужно их отобразить (вставить в страницу например).

Comment: при клике по новости меня перебрасывает по адресу http://127.0.0.1:5500/news/the-university-of-discovery/2021/sep/20/the-obesity-and-diabetes-epidemic-is-unsustainable-how-a-team-of-academics-aims-to-halt-the-trend. А как сделать, чтобы меня бросало на страницу news.html, на которой я бы уже достал нужный id и отобразил?

Comment: ...../news.html?id=......урл-кодированная-строка....